# Calling Cython functions from Numba jitted code

Tags: python, cython, numba

I know that a Numba-jitted function calling another jitted function will recognize this and automatically use a fast C calling convention rather than going through the Python object layer, and therefore avoid the high Python function call overhead:

```
import numba

@numba.jit
def foo(x):
    return x**2

@numba.jit
def bar(x):
    return 4 * foo(x)   # this will be a fast function call
```

My question is whether the same is true if I call a Cython function from Numba. So let's say I have a Cython module, `foo.pyx`:

```
cpdef double foo(double x):
    return x**2
```

As well as a standard Python module `bar.py`:

```
import numba
import foo

@numba.jit
def bar(x):
    return 4 * foo.foo(x)   # will this be a fast function call?
```

Will Numba recognize `foo.foo` as a C-callable function automatically or do I need to tell it manually by, say, setting up a CFFI wrapper?

**EDIT:** Upon further reflection, Cython functions are just standard "builtin" functions from the view of the Python interpreter. So the question can be made more general: does Numba optimize calls to builtin functions and methods to bypass the Python calling overhead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a limited set of builtin functions (from both the python standard library and numpy) that numba knows how to translate into native code:

- http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html
- http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html

Anything else will not be able to be jitted by Numba in `nopython` mode, thus resorting to `objectmode` which is much slower.

There is no direct way to pass a cython function to Numba and have it be recognized in `nopython` mode. Numba does have hooks for cffi:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html#cffi

that can be leveraged to call outside C code, that you might be able to rig up to call cython if you could create a low level wrapper at the C-level; I'm not 100% sure if this is possible though. I wrote about doing this for calling RMath functions from Numba:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160611082327/https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/calling-c-libraries-numba-using-cffi

It might be helpful in getting you started if you go that route.

Comment: Thanks, good information! 1) Do you know if this is a limitation of the Numba implementation or something which is inherently difficult? 2) You make it sound like there would be significant troubles in producing CFFI wrappers for Cython functions. Couldn't I simply take the function pointer on the C side and then wrap it using the proper signature as a CFFI/ctypes function object? Do you foresee any trouble with that approach?

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to use Cython's `cpdef`/`cdef`-functions (but not the `def`-functions) in nopython-numba:

1. step: `cdef`/`cpdef` function must be [marked as `api`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html?highlight=api#c-api-declarations) in the Cython code.
2. step: [`numba.extending.get_cython_function_address`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/extending/high-level.html#importing-cython-functions) can be used to get the address of the cpdef-function.
3. step: `ctypes` can be used to create a `CFunction` from the address of the cpdef-function, which can be used in numba-nopython code.

Read on for a more detailed explanation.

---

Even if the builtin-functions ([`PyCFunction`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyCFunction), the same as Cython's `def`-functions) are written in C, they don't have a signature which could be used by nopython-numba-code.

For example the `acos` function from the `math`-module, doesn't have the signature

```
`double acos(double)`
```

as one could expect, but [its signature](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/mathmodule.c#L1155) is

```
static PyObject * math_acos(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
```

So basically in order to call this function, numba would need to build a Python-float from the C-float at hand, but this is prohibited by `nopython=True`.

However, Cythons `cpdef`-functions are a little bit different: it is a small wrapper around a real `cdef`-function, whose arguments are raw C-types like `double`, `int` and so on. This `cdef`-function could be used by numba, only if its address were known.

Cython offers a way to find out the addresses of `cdef`-functions in a portable way: the addresses can be found in the attribute `__pyx_capi__` of the cythonized module.

However, not all `cdef` and `cpdef` functions are exposed in this way, but only ones which are explicitly marked as [C-api declarations](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html?highlight=api#c-api-declarations) or implicitly by being shared through a `pxd`-file.

Once the function `foo` of the `foomodule` is marked as `api`:

```
cpdef api double foo(double x):
    return x*x
```

the address of the cpdef-function `foo` can be found in `foomodule.__pyx_capi__`-dictionary:

```
import foomodule
foomodule.__pyx_capi
# {'foo': <capsule object "double (double)" at 0x7fe0a46f0360>}
```

It is surprisingly hard to extract the address from a [`PyCapsule`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/capsule.html) in Python. One possibility is to use [`ctypes.pythonapi`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), another (maybe easier one) is to utilize Cython to access Python's C-API:

```
%%cython
from cpython.pycapsule cimport  PyCapsule_GetPointer, PyCapsule_GetName
def address_from_capsule(object capsule):
    name = PyCapsule_GetName(capsule)
    return <unsigned long long int> PyCapsule_GetPointer(capsule, name)
```

which can be used as:

```
addr = address_from_capsule(foomodule.__pyx_capi__['foo'])
```

However, numba offers a similar functionality out of the box - [`get_cython_function_address`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/extending/high-level.html#importing-cython-functions) :

```
from numba.extending import get_cython_function_address
addr = get_cython_function_address("foomodule", "foo")
```

Once we got the address of the c-function, we can construct a `ctypes`-function:

```
import ctypes
foo_functype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double)
foo_for_numba = foo_functype(addr)
```

This function can be utilized for example as follows from nopython-numba:

```
from numba import njit
@njit
def use_foo(x):
    return foo_for_numba(x)
```

and now:

```
use_foo(5)
# 25.0
```

yields the expected result.

---

Arguments of ctype-functions which are understood by numba out of the box can be found [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/61ec1fd0f69aeadece218dccf4c39ebc5c7dfbc4/numba/core/typing/ctypes_utils.py#L14-L32) and are:

```
_FROM_CTYPES = {
    ctypes.c_bool: types.boolean,

    ctypes.c_int8:  types.int8,
    ctypes.c_int16: types.int16,
    ctypes.c_int32: types.int32,
    ctypes.c_int64: types.int64,

    ctypes.c_uint8: types.uint8,
    ctypes.c_uint16: types.uint16,
    ctypes.c_uint32: types.uint32,
    ctypes.c_uint64: types.uint64,

    ctypes.c_float: types.float32,
    ctypes.c_double: types.float64,

    ctypes.c_void_p: types.voidptr,
    ctypes.py_object: types.ffi_forced_object,
}
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how can we define `foo` arguments or return value to be numpy ndarrays?

Comment: @ibarrond I think there is no simple way of doing that (other as utilize an opaque python-object). You can look at the types of arguments  supported by numba out of the box: https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/61ec1fd0f69aeadece218dccf4c39ebc5c7dfbc4/numba/core/typing/ctypes_utils.py#L14-L32 and numpy's ndarray (as delivered by np.ctypeslib.ndpointer) is not one of them. You probably need to mimic it by hand in function interface.

Comment: Yeap, that's the same conclusion I reached. In the end I'm just ditching Numba and going for a full Cython approach.