# Calling Cython Functions from Numba njited function where numpy ndarrays are involved

Tags: python, numpy, cython, numpy-ndarray, numba

I am trying to do the following...

```py
# my_cython.pyx
cpdef api double cyf(double x, double[:] xarr, double[:] yarr) nogil:
    # Do stuff
    return result
```

```py
# my_cython.pxd
cpdef api double cyf(double x, double[:] xarr, double[:] yarr) nogil
```

```py
# main.py
from numba import njit

@njit
def myfunc():
   result = cyf(x, xarr, yarr)
   # Do more stuff
```

I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016076/calling-cython-functions-from-numba-jitted-code) on how to show Numba what the cython code is but I am not sure what to do about the memory slices that are defined in `cyf`'s arguments (these are 1-D float np.ndarrays).

I can get things to compile just fine and I can get the cython function's address using...

```py
from numba.extending import get_cython_function_address
addr = get_cython_function_address("mymod", "cyf")
```

But, I do not know what to use for the ctypes for the ndarrays...

```py
import ctypes
functype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, ???, ???)
cyf_numba = functype (addr)
```

I tried using pointers like...

```py
interp_functype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double,
                                   ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),
                                   ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
```

... but ended up with a njit error:

```
No implementation of function ExternalFunctionPointer((float64, float64*, float64*) -> float64) found for signature:
ExternalFunctionPointer(float64, array(float64, 1d, C), array(float64, 1d, C))
```

Thanks for any help!